# Windows column chart does not display legend

Tags: c#, charts, legend

```
BarGraph.Titles.Clear();
BarGraph.Titles.Add(cmbGraphOptions.SelectedItem.ToString());

Series series = new Series(seriesTitle);

series.ChartType = chartType == "Column" ? SeriesChartType.Column : SeriesChartType.Pie;
series.Palette = ChartColorPalette.EarthTones;

foreach (IGraphData t in mGraphVm.Data)
{
    if (t.XAxis != null && t.YAxis > 0)
    {
        series.Points.AddXY(t.XAxis, t.YAxis);
        series.Palette = ChartColorPalette.EarthTones;
        series.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        series.ToolTip = t.XAxis;
        series.Legend = "Legend1";
        series.IsVisibleInLegend = true;
    }
}
BarGraph.Series.Add(series);
```

Above code displays the pie and column chart. but in case of column chart it does not display the legend... whereas Pie chart does display the legends correctly.

However, for column chart.. when I change my code to below snippet, it does display the legend but this time it starts plotting the bar from the center instead of left.

```
foreach (IGraphData t in mGraphVm.Data)
{
    if (t.XAxis != null && t.YAxis > 0)
    {
        series = this.BarGraph.Series.Add(t.XAxis);
        series.Points.Add(t.YAxis);

        series.ToolTip = t.XAxis;
        series.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;

        //RnD
        //series.Points.AddXY(t.XAxis, t.YAxis);
        //series.Points.AddY(t.YAxis);

        //series.XValueMember = t.XAxis;
        //series.YValueMembers = t.YAxis.ToString();
    }
}
```

I need the graph to plot the point starting from left and with the legend.

Any help would be much appreciated.